# Why does a range query on a segment tree return at most $\lceil \log_2{N} \rceil$ nodes?

Tags: data-structures, arrays, search-trees, intervals

If an array $A[1 \ldots N]$ is represented using a segment tree having sets in each interval, why does a range query $[L\ldots R]$ returns at most $\lceil \log_2{N} \rceil$ sets (or disjoint intervals)?

If came across this statement while reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22075025/10820849).

To quote:

> Find a disjoint coverage of the query range using the standard segment
>   tree query procedure. We get $O(\log n)$ disjoint nodes, the union of
>   whose multisets is exactly the multiset of values in the query range.
>   Let's call those multisets $s_1, \dots, s_m$ (with $m \le \lceil \log_2 n \rceil$).

I tried searching for a proof, but couldn't find it on any site. Can anyone help me prove it?

Comment: Does Wikipedia help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree#Query

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I couldn't relate to querying procedure mentioned in Wikipedia. It queries on the intervals containing a given point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the basic idea.

Let a *dyadic* interval be an interval of the form
$$ [2^b a,2^b(a+1)-1] $$
for some integer $a,b \geq 0$.

**Claim 1.** If $m < 2^n$ then any interval of the form $[0,m-1]$ can be written as the disjoint union of at most $n$ dyadic intervals.

**Proof.** Expand $m$ as a sum of decreasing powers of 2:
$$ m = 2^{a_1} + \cdots + 2^{a_k}. $$
Then we can write
$$
[0,m-1] = [0,2^{a_1}-1] \cup [2^{a_1},2^{a_1}+2^{a_2}-1] \cup \cdots \cup [2^{a_1} + \cdots + 2^{a_{k-1}},2^{a_1} + \cdots + 2^{a_k}-1].
$$

**Claim 2.** If $0 \leq m_1 \leq m_2 \leq 2^n$ then any interval of the form $[m_1,m_2-1]$ can be written as the disjoint union of at most $2n$ dyadic intervals.

**Proof.** The binary expansion of $m_1$ and $m_2$ is of the form $m_1 = x0y, m_2 = x1z$, where $|y|=|z|$. Let $m = x10^{|z|}$. Using Claim 1, we can express $[0,m_2-m-1]$ as a union of at most $n$ dyadic intervals. Shifting these by $m$, we express $[m,m_2-1]$ as a union of at most $n$ dyadic intervals. Similarly, using Claim 1 we can express $[0,m-m_1-1]$ as a union of at most $n$ dyadic intervals. Shifting and inverting, we express $[m_1,m-1]$ as a union of at most $n$ dyadic intervals.

(In both cases, one needs to check that shifting, and possibly inverting, preservers an interval being dyadic.)

Comment: Is it necessary for $m_1$ and $m_2$ to have a $0$ or a $1$ in their binary expansion? Won't that be restricting the choices for $m_1$ and $m_2$?

Comment: You might have to zero-extend them.

Comment: For example, if $m_1 = 7$ and $m_2 = 10$, then you should write $m_1 = 0111$ and $m_2 = 1010$.